# Why does my program break? Why am I getting this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to make a program, using React and Firebase. I'm getting an error:

```
Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).
```

How can I initialize it only once to get rid of the error? Should I initialize it somewhere else?

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";

function Login() {
  var firebaseConfig = {
    ...
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  function verify(){
    var server = firebase.database().ref('servers/' + document.getElementById("code").value);
    server.on('value', function(snapshot) {

      if(snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().exist)
      {
        console.log(snapshot.val()); 
        alert("sucsess");
      } else{
        alert("fail");
      }
    });
  }
  function checkEnter(event) {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
      verify(); 
    }
  }


  return (
    <div>
     ...
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: hard to tell without context but if i'd guess your Login component is re-rendering at some point and re-initializing the app. maybe try putting your initialization in `componentDidMount` or similar to prevent duplicate calls?

Comment: How should I do it?

Comment: It seems that you have initialized the APP for Firebase twice. do you have such a thing as `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` somewhere else in your app?

Comment: Nope. But my program breaks when I come back from the SignIn. It's reloading the element, where I initialize firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);` with:

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp({});
}
```

The explanation is the same as I told you in the comment, I hope that would be enough.

Comment: Thank you! I works! I'll accept your answer in 2 minutes :))

Comment: Make sure it's all working out, you're welcome.